# a list have on-scroll listener goes to the top when loading new item

Tags: java, android, api, url, scrollview

i have list and i am loading data from API with multiple URL and when a URL is being executed and added to the list the list go to the first item in the list and then execute the URL

Answer (score 0):

the list might be going to the top because you are refreshing it with less objects than it had. What you can do is first save the current position (scroll) of the list, load the new item and then set the scroll back to the saved position.

Make sure that the saved position is not larger than the list size, in witch case you should need to scroll to the last item.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you are initiating your adapter every time new data is fetched from the api.

use this code in activity.It'll initiate the adapter if it is null or else it'll just update the data

```
 if (list_delivery_charge.getAdapter() == null) {
    deliveryAdapter = new DeliveryAdapter(getActivity(), deliveryData1);
    list_delivery_charge.setAdapter(deliveryAdapter);
   } 
    else {
        deliveryAdapter.repopulateData(deliveryData1);
        }
```

use this in adapter class to update data

```
 public void repopulateData(ArrayList<DeliveryChargeData> data) {
    this.deliveryChargeData = null;
    this.deliveryChargeData = data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

This helped me to stop jumping of listview to the first item every time new items are added to the list.